# OpenDs db location

Tags: opends

Can the data storage location be defined?

For instance, can the location of the application be installed in one location on the file system and the location of the directory for the database (db) be defined in another location on the file system?

Let us say that OpenDs has been installed at

C:\Users\james\OpenDS\

Can the db directory be defined as some thing other than

C:\Users\james\OpenDS\db

?

Such as

d:\db

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the DB location may be explicitly set when creating a new Database Backend.
However, once defined, it is not possible to change it.

This was discussed in OpenDJ mailing list in December 2011. See the thread starting here: http://lists.forgerock.org/pipermail/opendj/2011-December/001140.html

An alternate possibility, at least on Linux, is to move the db directory to another location and recreate OpenDS/db as a symbolic link to the new location.

Kind regards,

Ludovic.

Answer (score 0):

I found a link that talks about how to do this.

http://lists.forgerock.org/pipermail/opendj/2011-February/000069.html

A copy and paste from there is as follows:

It is possible to separate the installation directory (i.e. scripts,
libraries, etc) from the instance directory (i.e. configuration, db files,
logs, etc).

The easiest way to do this that I know if is to modify the contents of
the instance.loc file so that it contains the path "/var/opt/opendj". You
should then copy the following directories over from your install directory
except for the core schema files:

cd 
echo "/var/opt/opendj" > instance.loc
cp -r changelogDb config locks logs db /var/opt/opendj
rm /var/opt/opendj/config/schema/*.ldif

You should then be able to do the following once you've configured the
server according to your needs (e.g. the LDAP port):

cd /var/opt/opendj
/bin/start-ds

If anybody else has anything else to say about this topic I am all ears.

Comment: The procedure above is actually moving the whole OpenDJ instance to another location, not just the database files. Both are possible, and depends on what you're trying to achieve. Moving DB files can be useful if you have multiple DBs and want to have them on separated disks.